# Can't build Flux todo-mvc example

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, reactjs, reactjs-flux

Trying to build the flux-todomv example from facebook found here: 
 [flux-todomvc](https://github.com/facebook/flux/tree/master/examples/flux-todomvc)

I've run npm installed which has installed the dependencies.

When I run `npm start` I get back:

`watchify -o js/bundle.js -v -d .`

`1655542 bytes written to js/bundle.js (3.51 seconds)`

However the bundle.js file has not been created and when I open index.html there's a 404 error trying to get `bundle.js`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just pulled the repo to test, and I got it up and running without problems.

Here's the environment I'm using:

- OS X Mavericks
- Node v0.10.29
- npm 1.4.14
- git 1.9.4

Steps on the command line:

1. git clone https://github.com/facebook/flux.git
2. cd flux/examples/flux-todomvc/
3. npm install
4. npm start
5. ctrl-C
6. open index.html

Then if you want to hack on it, you would start up watchify again with `npm start` so your changes get transpiled to standard ECMAScript 5.

Comment: Not too sure why but this worked, I'd previously downloaded the repo as a zip file directly. Also I had to change the `/js/bundle.js` include to `./js/bundle.js`

Answer (score 0):

Simple run with this command line:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```